# How to dynamically retrieve all data from a year ago (Next Month) till the end of current Month based on year and month

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I am using LEFT JOIN table calendar to bring months columns even if there is no data for some of the months. It works if I say `tblCalendar.Year = 2016` so it will bring me all 12 month for current year. 
But I need data a year from the end of current month. 
So I am using data range

```
where       cal.YearNum >= YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AND cal.YearNum <=YEAR(GETDATE())
            AND cal.MonthNum >=MONTH(EOMONTH(GETDATE()) )+1 AND cal.MonthNum <=MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Bur for some reason it doesnt bring me anything. 
My query like this:

```
with cte_Data
AS      (
        select Month(effectiveDate) as MonthNum
                Year(EffectiveDate) as YearNum
        from MyTable 
        where EffectiveDate >=DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE())
        )
select * 
from tblCalendar cal left join cte_Data cd ON cal.MonthNum=cd.ClrEffMonth AND cal.YearNum=cd.ClrEffYear 
where       cal.YearNum >= YEAR(GETDATE())-1 AND cal.YearNum <=YEAR(GETDATE())
            AND cal.MonthNum >=MONTH(EOMONTH(GETDATE()) )+1 AND cal.MonthNum <=MONTH(GETDATE())
```

How can I manipulate those dates?
My table Calendar structure:
[image]

Comment: what's up with that `EOMONTH(GETDATE())`?

doesn't eomonth return a day? so we're basically just asking for the current month?

Comment: `EOMONTH(GETDATE())` brings the end of the current month

Comment: so the date range should be from september last year till end of the August this year

Comment: Provide table def and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  WHERE   ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
          ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) )
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide more context. use comment instead